# What does this error mean, and how do I resolve it? (java.lang.InternalError: Memory Pool not found)

Tags: java, memory-management

We're getting a very curious error in our application.

java.lang.InternalError: Memory Pool not found

```
 for ( final MemoryPoolMXBean bean : ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans() ) {
  final MemoryUsage usage = bean.getUsage(); // Error thrown on this line
  System.out.println(usage);
 }
```

What does this error mean, and how do I resolve it? I've googled around quite a bit, and it looks like few people have experienced it and no one has provided any good solutions.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I am running JRockit jrrt-3.0.0-1.6.0_sun_jdk1.6_16 on Linux.

Comment: Somebody help? Maybe I'll set a bounty on this when I gain the privilege.

Comment: Could you update this and include your platform and JRE?

Comment: What does `bean.isValid()` return?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in a controlled manner. This isn't critical code anyway. But I am just really curious what this mean, and what could have caused it.

Comment: Does the same thing happen with a later version of JRockit? It could be a bug that we have fixed. Try JRRT 4.0.1 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the pools has been deallocated while iterating over the list of MXBeans, hence it is not found anymore.

This is highly specific to the environment used, maybe you could provide some more details about the JVM and/or applicationserver/container in use.

Comment: If this is true, it breaks the spec for `MemoryPoolMXBean.getUsage()` which says it will return null if the pool no longer exists.  Unfortunately, the source code for JRockit is closed, and the bug database isn't even open to the public.